# Can't add UIBarButtonItem to independent UINavigationBar

Tags: cocoa-touch, uinavigationbar

I am programatically adding a UINavigationBar to a UIView, and now need to add a UIBarButtonItem to it. I am trying to use the following:

```
UIBarButtonItem *doneButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemDone target:self action:@selector(dismissView)];
[header setItems:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:doneButton, nil] animated:NO];
[doneButton release];
```

My app crashes and I find this in the console:

`*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UIBarButtonItem setNavigationBar:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x4b75c00'`

Would appreciate it if someone could please point out what am I doing incorrectly here.

Thanks.
Ricky.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

`UINavigationBar` accepts an array of [UINavigationItem](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UINavigationItem_Class/Reference/UINavigationItem.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/UINavigationItem) objects, each of which contain properties about a given level of the navigation hierarchy. You probably want to create a new `UINavigationItem` and then set its `rightBarButtonItem` property to your Done button.

Answer (score 4):

It's unlikely you need to create a new `UINavigationItem` as the answer currently states.  In contrast if you already have a `UINavigationBar` initialized from a nib which also contains a view, you can just add your `UINavigationItem` to the `topItem` property of your `UINavigationBar`.  Something like this:

```
UIBarButtonItem *closeBtn = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Close" 
                                                             style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered 
                                                            target:self 
                                                            action:@selector(closeBtnPressed)];
self.navigationBar.topItem.leftBarButtonItem = closeBtn;
[closeBtn release];
```